# how jaxb.index file handled by axis2?

Tags: jaxb, apache-axis

I am trying to add jaxb.index files to completely avoid the search for JAXB classes in my web service project and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwbs_tuning_jaxbcontext.html says that " If the package does not contain any JAXB classes, an empty jaxb.index file must be placed in the package".  My EAR file contains third party jars and my web service project as utility jar in which I put jaxb.index file properly.

My question is that Does JAXB.newInstance search all classpath in which  has  third party jars not containing jaxb classes?

If yes it doesn't make sense to put empty jaxb.index to all package of third party jar such as logging. Does it?